# Como verificar se tem algum erro no blade do laravel com a tag @error laravel 5.8.13?

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Bem no laravel 5.8.13 houve uma atualização em que ao inves de usar:

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
@endif
```

pode-se usar:

```
@error('email')
    <span>{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

porem eu queria saber com verificar se tem qualquer erro não um especifico com a mesma função de:

```
@if($errors->all())
    <span>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Existe o `$errors->any()` que faz isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,
Pelo que entendi da sua dúvida.
Você já tentou usar o código abaixo:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Obrigado cara tbm funciona, mas eu queria saber se existe uma versão como tag, usando a tag @error, mas já ajudou